# Plotting a set of data with time in hh:mm format in x axis in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a code which goes like this:

```
clc;clear;close all
%% 
Time=linspace(16.8,17.8,230400)';
Field=linspace(50,145,230400)';
figure('units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1])
plot(Time,Field)
%% 
figure('units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1]) 
hammng_wndw_size=4096;
window=hamming(hammng_wndw_size); %window size
noverlap=512; % the noverlaps its the no. of points for repeating the window
nfft=4096; %size of fft
fs=32; %sampling freq
[Sp,F,T,P]=spectrogram(Field,window,noverlap,nfft,fs,'yaxis');
T_forspectrogrm=T./3600+Time(1);
surf(T_forspectrogrm,F,10*log10(P),'edgecolor','none','FaceColor','interp');
axis tight;ylim([0 4]);view(0,90);
colormap(jet);colorbar;
```

The result of this plot is these two figures:
[image: Plot]
[image: Spectrogram]

The xaxis is time and y axis is some other quantity, lets say field. Now, when I plotting, the x axis starts from 16.8 to 17.8 for first figure and 16.8 and 18.8 for second figure. This actually corresponds to 16:48:00 to 17:48:00 and similarly for the second one. How do I have to modify the program to convert the x-axis into hh:mm format do this job?

I tried in this fashion
`TimeInReqFrmat=datestr(Time(:,1),'HH:MM:SS')`, but this gives me a string of characters.

I am using Matlab 2016a.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You approach was almost right. You need to use `datetimes`. It's just a bit tricky to convert decimal numbers to date times

```
x = [16.8;17.8]

H = floor(x); % hour
m = floor((x-H)*60); % minute
S = (x-H)*60-m; % second
% create date vector
DateVec = datetime(0,0,0,H,m,S);

plot(DateVec,rand(size(DateVec)))
% set the tick format
xtickformat('HH:mm')
```

[image: axis]

There are many options to set the [`xtickformat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xtickformat.html#bu6ia4o-datefmt).

If you have unix-time, you can convert it right away

```
datetime(x,'ConvertFrom','datenum')
```

If you have just time, you will need to come up with a date for a proper `datetime`. Otherwiese you can also think of using `duration`.

Comment: Dear @Max, 

Thank you for your time. In the program you have suggested, you have taken the starting and ending time and converted into the format that I require, which is of size 2 by 1 and plotting wrt to rand(size(DateVec).)In my case the cell size is different and it’s causing a problem. Further, datetime function create date 30-Nov--0001 along with time 16:48:00. I dont want date to be shown- time itself is sufficient.

Also, I cannot employ 'xtickformat' as it was introduced in R2016b and I am using R2016a

Thank you.